# RecyclerView adapter update in handler

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am new in android development. My application have timer like 8sec , 7sec ,6sec and so on...  So i have put time in model class and using handler i am updating that model class value on every sec secondly i have to update my recycler view.. Here my code (till now i have tried this below)

```
  public void startTimerUpdate() {

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductDetail>>() {
                }.getType();
                arrayList = gson.fromJson(ReadSharePrefrence(getActivity(), ALLPRODUCT), type);
                Log.d("UpdateTime", getTimeInCounter(arrayList.get(0).getCounter()));

                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
```

but at a every second i am getting 'UpdateTime' perfectly in my log but recyclerView is not updating.

Guide me

yes , i had bind arraylist to recyclerview adpater here is code.

```
   recyclerAdapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList, getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: Is your arrayList binded with your RecyclerView?

Comment: yes , i have updated my question check it

Comment: Please go over through the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position of the item which you want to update it's data you can try to use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` method of adapter instead of `recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Here's the link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)

> Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed.
>   Equivalent to calling notifyItemChanged(position, null);.
>
> This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It
>   indicates that any reflection of the data at position is out of date
>   and should be updated. The item at position retains the same identity.

**Edit**:

If you have multiple items updated on timer you can take

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductDetail>>() {
                }.getType();
    arrayList = gson.fromJson(ReadSharePrefrence(getActivity(), ALLPRODUCT), type);
```

this code block out of handler and just handle your operation getCounter() in handler. With this approach, you avoid doing read/write in handler in every 1 second.

Comment: means, notifying adapter and reading shared preferences are hard works to do in every 1 second.

Comment: Acatully i m confused about what is better for my process, i want to update my arrayList on every sec. so which one is better for me Service , timer or handler ?

Comment: so what i have to ?

Comment: avoid reading from shared preferences in every 1 second. read once keep in memory update your data and notify. and when you need for example if view get destroy save your data in memory to shared pref.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139016/discussion-between-sneha-archirayan-and-savepopulation).

Answer (score 1):

try this in handler:

```
arrayList.clear();
Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductDetail>>() {
                }.getType();
arrayList.addAll(gson.fromJson(ReadSharePrefrence(getActivity(), ALLPRODUCT), type));
recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```